# Get path to File in executing project c#

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, filepath, opennlp

I have two separate projects in Solution.

First project is just a **Test Console** project. 
And the second project is **Common Lib** project.

I have static class in **Common Lib** project that contains a static method which requires reading the file (for OpenNLP).

```
var sentenceDetector = new EnglishMaximumEntropySentenceDetector("EnglishSD.nbin");
```

I added file "EnglishSD.nbin" into **Common Lib** project. I changed the property of that file to '**Content**' and '**Copy always**' too. It does add that file to bin/debug folder of **Common Lib** project. 
**EDIT:** 'EnglishSD.nbin' is located in folder OpenNLP/EnglishSD.nbin

Issue: When I run **test console** project which uses the static function in **Common lib** project. It tries to look for 'EnglishSD.nbin' into the bin folder of **Test Console** Project instead of **Common Lib** project. Which leads to an error of 'FileNotFound'.

Is there any way to get the path of the file without worrying about where it's being called from?

Answer (score 0):

So your **Test Console** references your **Common Lib**? Then, when you build the **Test Console**, the `CommonLib.dll` will be copied to the **Test Console** project folder. I don't know if there is an automatic way of copying dependencies of libraries that are referenced by the main project...

But you can setup that. Use the post-build-event of the **Test Console** project and copy your required file manually (I assume that your **Common Lib** project folder is `/Common Lib`):
`copy "$(SolutionDir)Common Lib\EnglishSD.nbin" "$(TargetDir)"`

Answer (score 0):

My bad guys. I actually had 'EnglishSD.nbin' in the folder. Therefore it created a folder in TestConsole projects bin/debug and placed files there.

So I just needed to change the path to (FolderName)/EnglishSD.nbin.

```
 var sentenceDetector = new EnglishMaximumEntropySentenceDetector("OpenNLP/EnglishSD.nbin");
```